# Error while creating a symbolic link in debian/rules

Tags: debian, symlink

I'm trying to modify my `debian/rules` file to create me symbolic link.
My package has two files:

1. `/etc/logger-server1.json`
2. `/etc/logger-server2.json`

Now in my `debian/rules` file I created the following entry:

```
override_dh_install:
dh_install
if [ "$(PROJECT)" == "server1" ]; then \
    echo "It is server1"
    ln -sf /etc/logger-server1.json /etc/logger-cfg.json
else
    echo "It is server2"
    ln -sf /etc/logger-server2.json /etc/logger-cfg.json
fi
```

But when I compile it I get the following error:

```
install: cannot stat 'etc/logger-cfg.json': No such file or directory
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'install' failed
```

Is there any way to solve it?

P.s.
When I'm creating it manually it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ouch.

### "package time" vs "install time"

you first must understand, that there's a difference between building a Debian package and installing it.

The sole purpose of `debian/rules` is to **create** a package.
It's typically used to "build" files from the sources (e.g. compiling files into binaries; normally this is not done "directly", but by invoking the build-system of the sources you are packaging), and arrange them in such a way that you can put them into the `.deb` archive.
Once you have a `.deb` file, you can install it on any machine.
(And typically, the machine where you build the package is *not* the target machine(s) where you install the package)

However, the scripts that are present in `debian/rules` are *only* run during the build-process. They are not executed when the package is being installed!

So `debian/rules` is really just a script (a Makefile, to be precise), that is run when you *build* the package to do all the heavy lifting.
The sole purpose of this script is to create a `.deb` file.

So whatever command you have in it, will be executed with the priviliges of the running user.
The commands can be arbitrary, and don't need to have anything to do with the package at hand.

In your specific example `ln -sf /etc/logger-server1.json /etc/logger-cfg.json` will attempt to create a symlink in the `/etc` directory **of the machine where you build the package**.

This is most likely not what you want. I guess what you want to do is create a symlink *in the package* (that is: you want the symlink on every machine that installs the package).

Luckily for you, `dpkg-buildpackage` is usually invoked with non-root powers (these days). And non-superusers are typically not allowed to create symlinks in `/etc`.
(Similarily, your script could contain `rm -r /` (**DO NOT RUN THIS**) which would just wipe out your entire harddisk while building the package if your user has/had enough power).

### use `dh_link`

In order to create symlinks inside your package, use `dh_link`, using use `debian/*.links`.

Eg. assuming you are building two packages `server1` and `server2` you would have something like:

```sh
$ cat debian/server1.links
/etc/logger-server1.json /etc/logger-cfg.json
$ cat debian/server2.links
/etc/logger-server2.json /etc/logger-cfg.json
```

So if you install the `server1` package, it will create a symlink from */etc/logger-server1.json*, and if you install the `server2` package , it will create a symlink from */etc/logger-server2.json*.

If you want to make the actual decision a install-time decision (e.g. you are installing a single package `myserver` and ask the user what they want during the installation process), you ought to checkout how to write [maintainer scripts](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts).

### think again

however, I think you are overengineering things.
The `/etc` directory is special, as it is reserved for the *administrator* to adjust to their needs.
Packages need to be extra careful if they change things in there (as this might undo all the changes the admin did).

If you just install files into `/etc/`, *debhelper* will apply extra logic to protect changed files in there (basically asking the admin, whether they want to keep the old file or install the new file).
But if you bypass this security with your own scripts, then chances are high that you will break things.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Yes, I don't want to create it where I compile but where I install it with `sudo dpkg -i` (so I have permissions) , But I don't understand why after I changed inside the `if` statement `ln -sf` to `dh_link` I still get the same error on build time, didn't you said it will also occure on installation?